# remove doi field in bibliography, but keep the link

Tags: biblatex

I have some citations which render rather ugly, including the DOI after the journal, as in

> J. Doe and J. Doe, “Great breakthrough”, Nature Communications 13, 10.1038/s12345-678-90123-4 (2022).

I would like to remove the `10.1038/s12345-678-90123-4` stuff, but keep the journal name as clickable link. I tried setting `doi=false` and some related options, but to no avail. If I remove the `doi` field from the `references.bib` file, then the `10.1038...` will disappear, but so will the link.

MWE:

`example.tex`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=phys,doi=false,eprint=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Text~\cite{author1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`references.bib`

```
@Article{author1,
  author       = {Jane Doe and John Doe},
  date         = {2022-01},
  journaltitle = {Nature Communications},
  title        = {Great Breakthrough},
  doi          = {10.1038/s12345-678-90123-4},
  number       = {1},
  volume       = {13},
  publisher    = {Springer Science and Business Media {LLC}},
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex-phys` shows the DOI only if the `pages` field is not present. But if `pages` is not present, it will even ignore the `doi` option and will always show the DOI.

If you don't want that, you can use the following redefinition of the `note+pages` macro

```
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
}
```

With this definition the DOI output is controlled only be the `doi` option.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=phys,doi=false,eprint=false,url=false]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author1,
  author       = {Jane Doe and John Doe},
  date         = {2022-01},
  journaltitle = {Nature Communications},
  title        = {Great Breakthrough},
  doi          = {10.1038/s12345-678-90123-4},
  number       = {1},
  volume       = {13},
  publisher    = {Springer Science and Business Media {LLC}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Text~\cite{sigfridsson,author1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: J. Doe and J. Doe, “Great breakthrough”, Nature Communications 13 (2022).]